# Glassfish 3.1 JDBC Connection Pool to MS SQL Server 2012 named instance

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, glassfish-3

i'm trying to add a jdbc connection pool -- within glassfish 3.1.2 running on windows -- to a mssql server 2012 named instance. so i made the usual settings, such as, `user`, `password`, `databaseName`, `url`, and `serverName`.

however, as this is a named instance, i have to provide the name of the instance somewhere. so i tried to add an additional attribute `instanceName`, to no avail. providing the fully quallified url -- with ip, instanceName, user, ... didn't succeed either.

all the attempts resulted in an error message that the user X -- that i used in the properties -- can't be authenticated. the error message is logged on the default instance, not on the instance i tried to connect to.

in the general settings i chose `javax.sql.XADatasource` -- though i tried it with the plain DataSource as well -- as the **ResourceType**, and `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource` as the **Datasource Classname**.

appreciate your feedback

EDIT:

here are the fields -- Additional Properties:

```
InstanceName = WEB
ServerName   = <DB_SERVER_IP>
DatabaseName = FooDB
User         = <USER_X>
Password     = <USER_X_PASSWORD>
URL          = jdbc:sqlserver://
```

Comment: Do you have the SQL Server Browser service running? If not you cannot cannot connect to a named instance from JDBC at all. (NOTE: I am not saying this is the actual cause, but it can interfere with troubleshooting)

Comment: yes, the service is running.

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: Or better: the values assigned to each property

Comment: are you able to connect to SQL Server using your sql client? could be that user does not exists. you should also check your SQL Server authentication mode.

Comment: yes, i can connect to the database in other ways -- like providing the complete url with credentials; thus not using the JDBC Connection in Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the secret is -- i know i left out that property --, to **not** to have the port property set.